# Can JWPlayer in HLS mode handle timecode resets after #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY

Tags: jwplayer, http-live-streaming

We are using the JWPlayer SDK and it appears that it's not able to handle a timecode reset after an #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag.  According to HLS spec the player should be able to handle this.  We are resetting timecodes after certain content blocks and always using an #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag, but JWPlayer is playing the first fragment and then a minute or more of silence and doesn't appear to know how to handle that.

This is for an AAC audio stream.

If we do not include the timecodes at all JWPlayer doesn't have an issue.  But then VideoJS doesn't handle the stream.  Could really use some help here.

JWPlayer doesn't appear to have direct support and instead monitors stack overflow so I'm posting this here.  I can provide stream links if needed.

Answer (score 0):

JW Player does have direct support at https://support.jwplayer.com/

Please note that you will need to be signed in with your JW account credentials in order to submit a new support case to us.

Thanks,
Todd

Comment: Thanks, I finally did find the support.  It was a bit hidden, but I tracked it down.  Haven't heard back from them yet, but hope to soon.  Thank you.